# ¿Cómo arreglo esta sumatoria en c++?

Tags: c++

Tengo este código que me marcaron de tarea, pero se supone que por cada línea se aumenten los asteriscos, pero al inicio se me imprime uno en la primera línea, otra vez uno en las segunda línea y así:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, i;
    cout << "¿Cuántas veces desea leer la sentencia?: ";
    cin >> n;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i=i+1){ // i++ ó i += 1
       cout << i << ". Hola mundo." << endl;
    }    
    cout << i << endl;

    cout << "CON J" << endl;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){ // j = j + 1
        cout << j << ". Hola mundo." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Si pudieran ayudarme a corregir este error para que por cada línea que pida se aumente bien los asteriscos, gracias.

Comment: Todo codigo va como texto, [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/436220/edit) tu pregunta y agrega eso

Comment: Soy daltónico y no puedo ver lo escrito en la imagen que compartes. De todas maneras, esta es una página sobre código no una página de capturas de pantalla ¿Por qué no pones el código?.

Comment: Perdón soy nuevo en esto y no sabía como poner código

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agregar un "=" en el while del bucle anidado.

```
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int lineas, cl, ca;
    cout<<"Lineas: ";
    cin >> lineas;
    
    cl = 0;
    do {
        ca = 0;
        do {
            cout<<"*";
            ca++;
        }while(ca <= cl);
        cout << endl;
        cl++;
    }while(cl < lineas);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Ya que antes, en la segunda línea no se volvía a ejecutar el bucle porque 1 < 1 no es válido.

Primera línea (no se vuelve a ejecutar el bucle):

```
1 <= 0  no válido
```

Segunda línea (solo se ejecuta 1 vez el bucle otra vez):

```
1 <= 1  válido
2 <= 1  no válido
```

y así...

Answer (score 0):

El objeto `std::string` tiene un constructor en el que puedes indicar un número y un carácter:

[Segundo constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
constexpr basic_string( size_type count, 
                        CharT ch, 
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Esto creará una cadena de caracteres con el carácter indicado en el segundo parámetro repetido tantas veces como el valor indicado en el primer parámetro.

Usando ese constructor, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

int main(){
    using namespace std;

    int lineas;
    cout << "¿Cuántas veces desea leer la sentencia?: ";
    cin >> lineas;
    
    for (int linea = 1; linea <= lineas; ++linea)
        cout << string(linea, '*') << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc5NDoIwEAXgdecUE1wURBPduJDSE3gEN02ppAkMpD8r49krRcVZvXx5Mxk9z0c9KOpT2lnSQ@wMCjv54IwaJcIfF7LUSwBLAUdlqayewKJfEEmNxs9KG/ShawBY7gyWjPINMD3FgEJgcVvlikVGSyjlVsJlgD0mh@W2iy2em28U7a@Kdb2mCth2@fNbufoB@Z5XWfmdeH7GmRAd4amBV0oXeAM)</kbd>.